# how can I have div and iframe in same area?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have iframe in my page. I need to show `<div>` in my parent page, but i cannot see until I hide my frame. Is it possible to force the frame to be in background. I don't want to open popup window instead of `<div>`.

parent.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".Class1").click(function() {
            var str = "<div>Some content</div>";
            $(".main_frame").hide();
            $(str).appendTo('body');
        });
    });
</script>

<a class='Class1' href='#'>text</a>
<div class='frame_div'>
    <iframe class='main_frame' name='main_frame' src='child.php'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: allowTransparency="true" for iframe that have .Class1 according to blachawk's answer. It's make it work in IE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append your new "div" statement to your body on click, then you can do something like this...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".Class1").click(function() {
            var str = "<div>Some content</div>";
            $('body').append(str);
            //$(".main_frame").hide();
            //$(str).appendTo('body');

        });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I expected.
1. I need to see my frame before and after clicking on link. If I put visibility:hidden; then It is hidden even before clicking.
2. anyway if I call $(".main_frame").hide(); I will not be able to see my frame in background

Comment: then why are you trying to hide() it if you don't want to hide it? just remove the line that is telling you to hide() your iframe, if you want to see it the entire time.

Comment: I cannot see my div if iframe is not hidden

Comment: the div you are trying to see is "<div>Some Content</div>"? if so, that is because you need to adjust your code.  let me update my statement...

Comment: Yes it is <div>Some Content</div>. I append this div to body by calling $('body').append(str);

Answer (score 0):

I have just added the following to my css and it worked. I also removed $(".main_frame").hide(); of course.

```
.main_frame {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```